# I want to know the total wood requirement for my sofa set

Tags: hardwood

I want to make one three seater and 2 single seaters. the dimensions of the same are attached.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a plan from which these images are pulled? If so, what does it call for? If not, well, you can add up the lengths just the same as someone here could do it for you.

Comment: You need a [cut list](https://www.woodcraft.com/blog_entries/a-pro-s-guide-to-cut-lists). It's easy to make your own, no special tools required. Just write down all the parts for each piece in a table along with rough dimensions, final dimensions, etc. From that you can calculate total board feet. Most people will add an extra 10-30% for waste because it's a lot easier than trying to plan out what to do with every board before you even buy the lumber.

Answer (score 1):

**First**,

If you are planning to make your own furniture (*or cabinetry or anything with wood*) then learning how to calculate the stock needed is a skill **YOU** need to **learn**.

**Second**,

Question about woodworking are better served on the [woodworking stack](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/).

There is a wealth of info for you to research on [internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how%20to%20calculate%20the%20material%20requirements%20for%20building%20furniture&t=ffsb&ia=web) websites or [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=HOW%20to%20calculate%20stock%20requirments%20for%20building%20furniture) to learn these skills. If you find you are stuck and need a particular question answered then post your question and explain how your research as not yielded the info you need.